# Snort rules detection

Tags: snort

I have a not detection snort rule in pcap.
Some pcap files, this rule is detected, some other not. I tried lot of possible options, but no detection.
Maybe if someone may help me, it should be good ;-)

Here is the rule that is detected on 2 pcap files.

alert ip any any <> any any (msg:"TEST 1"; content:"forum.php" ; nocase ; classtype:trojan-activity; sid:6000003; rev:0;)

This rule is not detected with 2 other pcap files.
Wireshark shows me that forum.php is inside the not detected pcap

Where is the problem ?

Thanks for help